# Show that $\mathcal{L}$ is a $\lambda$-system.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mathcal{L}$ be the set of Lebesgue measurable subsets of $(0,1]$ such that $\lambda(A+x)=\lambda(A)$ where $A+x:=\{y\in (0,1]: y-x\in A\}$. I try to show that $\mathcal{L}$ is a $\lambda$-system.

I check definition:

(1) Clearly, $(0,1]\in \mathcal{L}$.

But I am stuck on the another ones

(2) for $E_1, E_2\in \mathcal{L}$ with $E_1\subset E_2$, how to show that
$$
\lambda(E_2\setminus E_1+x)=\lambda(E_2\setminus E_1)?
$$

(3) for $\{E_i\}_{i\ge 1}$ pairwise disjoint, show that
$$
\lambda(\cup_i E_i+x)=\lambda(\cup_i E_i)?
$$

Note that $$\lambda(\cup_i E_i+x)=\lambda(\cup_i (E_i+x))=\sum_i \lambda(E_i+x)=\sum \lambda(E_i)=\lambda(\cup_i E_i) $$

Comment: Do you know how the class of Lebesgue measurable sets is defined?

Comment: In the definition of $A+x$, I don’t think you want to restrict to $y \in (0, 1]$? Otherwise $(0, 1]$ is most certainly *not* in $\mathcal{L}$.

Comment: For (3), it seems you already figured it out. For (2), after fixing the definition of $A+x$ note that $E_2 \setminus E_1 + x = (E_2 + x) \setminus (E_1 + x)$ and that $\lambda(E_2 \setminus E_1) = \lambda(E_2) - \lambda(E_1)$ when $E_1 \subset E_2$ and $\lambda(E_1) < +\infty$.